# A jQuery code being applied in many input, but I want it only on a intended input which is a (search box)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, conflict

I am creating an expanding search box, when it is on focus it gets expanded and contracts when off the focus, but I have in my page many buttons, textboxes and radio buttons, when on click or focus other same to search box gets expand and contract.

```
         The code I am using:
```

```
    <script  type="text/javascript" src="for admg/jquery-latest.min.js"></script> 

    <script type="text/javascript">
        //global vars
        var inputWdith = '150px';
        var inputWdithReturn = '100px';
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('input').focus(function () {
                //clear the text in the box.
             //   $(this).val(function () {
             //       $(this).val('');
             //   });
                //animate the box
               $(this).animate({
                    width: inputWdith

                }, 500)
            });

            $('input').blur(function () {
                $(this).val(' Search  ');
                $(this).animate({
                    width: inputWdithReturn 
                }, 800) 
            });
        });

    </script>
```

Comment: Who wrote this code? Do you realise that the search value is being cleared on every focus? I don't like that.

Comment: But when I try to uncomment the following code //   $(this).val(function () { //   $(this).val(''); //   });  what I see in the search box is the following: "function () { " and appreciate a solution from you. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `$('input')`, you select every kind of input. Give your search box an `id` or `class` attribute, e.g. `<input id="searchBox" type="text" />`, then select it with `$('#searchBox')` (or `$('.searchBox')` for a `class` attribute).

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I made $('input').focus(function() to $('#searchBox').focus(function () and added <input id="searchBox" it is a bit better, before there was animation on any input click, but now animation is after releasing the click on inputs.

Comment: Another change I made was $('#searchBox').blur(function () instead of $('input').blur(function ().  Now it is working. Again thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you searchbox is an aspnet control like this.

```cs
    <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="texbox"></asp:TextBox>
```

Then the correct selector would be something like this:

```js
    $('#<%=texbox.ClientID %>')
```

Hope it helps